# ¿Es un "chiringuito" un "chiringo pequeño"?

Tags: etimología, españa, sustantivos

En España usamos para la palabra *[chiringuito](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8rjGoDg)* como "quiosco o puesto de bebidas al aire libre". Sin embargo, el DLE no da una etimología para la palabra. Lo primero que se me ocurre es que pueda venir de *chiringo* mediante la aplicación de un diminutivo. Sin embargo, su definición es tal que así:

> **[chiringo, ga](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8rgFU4D)**
>
> ```
> De or. amer.
> ```
>
> 1. adj. coloq. P. Rico. Pequeño, corto, escaso. *Esa prenda le queda chiringa.*
> 2. m. Sev. Vaso de aguardiente.
> 3. m. Hond. andrajo (‖ pedazo o jirón de tela).
> 4. f. Cuba y P. Rico. cometa (‖ armazón).

El *Diccionario de americanismos* añade las siguientes acepciones como sustantivo:

> PR. Caballo pequeño, de inferior calidad. rur.
>   PR. metáf. Vehículo pequeño y en mal estado. pop + cult → espon.
>   Ho. Pedazo de algo, generalmente de ropa rota o deshilachada. pop ^ desp.

Y otra como adjetivo:

> PR. Referido a una prenda de vestir, que le queda pequeña a la persona que la lleva. rur.

No sé si alguna de estas acepciones habrá dado origen a la palabra *chiringuito*. La más plausible parece ser la acepción sevillana de "vaso de aguardiente", que haría que en Sevilla un *chiringuito* fuera un lugar donde se sirven chiringos, que tampoco iría muy desencaminado, la verdad.

El caso es que en el CORDE no encuentro ningún caso de *chiringo* pero sí unos pocos de *chiringuito*. En el CREA hay muchos más casos de *chiringuito* y alguno de *chiringo* con el mismo sentido de "quiosco de bebidas", formado por acortamiento (similar al *bocata* como acortamiento de *bocadillo*), pero ninguno como "vaso de aguardiente".

Esto podría hacer pensar que fue al revés: *chiringo* derivaría de *chiringuito* en su acepción de "vaso de aguardiente". Pero ahora nos vamos al NTLLE y vemos que *chiringuito* se recoge por la RAE desde 1983, mientras que la acepción sevillana de *chiringo* se recoge desde... 1983 también. Empate.

¿Es pues este el origen de *chiringuito*? ¿Se deriva de la acepción de *chiringo* como "vaso de aguardiente"? ¿O tiene otro origen?

Comment: En Colombia usamos Chirringo (doble r) para algo pequeño y obviamente Chirringuito para algo pequeñito

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He encontrado otro posible origen en este artículo: http://www.elcorreo.com/vizcaya/20080803/sociedad/chiringuito-primigenio-20080803.html

En el [foro de CVC](https://cvc.cervantes.es/foros/leer_asunto1.asp?vCodigo=41145) dan otras fuentes del periodico *La Verdad* pero uno de los artículos no cuenta exactamente la misma historia y el otro que citan no está accesible, falla el enlace.

Transcribo las partes relevantes que hablan del origen de la palabra *chiringuito* con el significado de bar de playa:

> El viajero se sienta en una terraza de la playa. Toma una caña y unas
> patatas bravas, plato en extinción, mientras observa a los
> parroquianos. Parece un bar animado, con personalidad, y hay un señor
> mayor repantingado que hace comentarios en voz alta. El viajero lee la
> servilleta y pone 'First chiringuito in Spain'.[...]
> Aquel era el primer chiringuito de España. De hecho, se llama El Chiringuito y de ahí salió la palabra.

Más adelante dice:

> El chiringuito lo abrió el capitán Calafell en 1913 y luego lo cogió
> su padre. En Sitges estaba entonces el Pabellón de Mar, más para
> ricos, para los indianos, y al lado, este quiosco. Entonces apenas
> había en el pueblo algunos chalets del señorío de Barcelona, de
> abogados y médicos. Lo de chiringuito viene precisamente de los
> indianos, que cuando querían un café decían: «Ponme un chiringuito».
>
> La cosa viene de Cuba. Resulta, explica don Juan, que los negros de
> las plantaciones de caña metían el café en una media y luego la
> apretaban para que saliera un chorrito. Al chorro le decían chiringo,
> y de ahí chiringuito, un chorrito de café. El nombre hizo gracia, y
> por extensión se empezó a llamar así al local donde lo servían.

Comment: Interesante, me recuerda al origen de la palabra "peña" como "grupo de gente".

Answer (score 1):

Pongo como posible respuesta lo que acabo de encontrar en una de las fichas del *Fichero general* de la RAE. En 1974 José S. Serna publicaba lo siguiente en su libro *Cómo habla La Mancha. Diccionario manchego*:

> **chiringuito**. (De *chingar*, beber con frecuencia vino o licores; influido por *chinguirito*, aguardiente en Cuba y Méjico, y *chiribitil*, pieza o cuarto muy pequeño.) m. Tenderete donde se expenden (3.ª acep. R.A.E.) viandas y principalmente vino y licores.

Comprobamos que, efectivamente, la palabra *[chingar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8pLhBqB)* tiene esa acepción, que *[chinguirito](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8pgkZVo)* existe también como "aguardiente" o "bebida de aguardiente", y que *[chiribitil](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8r9dhEU)* es un "cuarto pequeño". No resulta descabellada la opción de la metátesis *chinguirito* > *chiringuito* por influencia de *chiribitil*, que se usaba en España:

> *La mujer entornó el ventanuco por donde entraba en el chiribitil la luz del sol poniente y se marchó en puntillas.*
>
> Emilia Pardo Bazán, "Insolación", 1889 (España).

A fin de cuentas, un *chiringuito* es un *chiribitil* donde se dispensan *chinguiritos*.

---

Por otra parte, y para dar más validez a la [respuesta de @blonfu](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/26187/12637), aclarar que la palabra *chiringuito* aparece en algunos textos de la hemeroteca de la BNE. Lo curioso es que en el primero de ellos la palabra tenía otro significado:

> Después de las cinco ya es otra cosa; cambia totalmente el aspecto de la
>   población [Huelva] y empieza el momento supremo de divertirse. La *manguara* de González Bías, el *chiringuito* y las almejas *reealentáas*, son aperitivos excelentes que preparan el estómago para una buena comida [...].
>
> El Liberal (Madrid). 1/2/1895, página 2.

Y en un texto posterior ya se hace alusión al bar mencionado por @blonfu:

> *Barcelona 16*. — Esta madrugada, en el «bar» Chiringuito, establecido en la Puerta de la Paz, en el puerto, se promovió un formidable escándalo, del que fué principal protagonista el diestro Larita.
>
> El Imparcial (Madrid). 17/7/1924, página 5.

Curiosamente, cada vez que el bar salía en las noticias era por algún suceso:

> BARCELONA 14 (5 t.). — El Juzgado que instruye la causa por agresión a Antonio Martínez "Medialuna", hecho ocurrido en el bar Chiringuito, ha recibido declaración
>   a varios testigos, entre ellos la mujer llamada Matilde flor.
>
> La Voz (Madrid). 14/3/1925, página 6.

Answer (score 0):

Repondiendo a la pregunta inicial...en Honduras específicamente Chiringos - se refiere a la ropa, por lo general ropa usada o desgastada lo que en ingles sería worn-out clothes.

Frecuentemente se escucha - Lo han corrido de la casa y con todo y sus chiringos.

Tambien se usa en diminutivo - Chiringuito al referirse en una manera todavia más despectiva.

Vete y llevate tus chiringuitos!

Son meramente hondureñismos, que solo las personas de dicha región pueden comprender y aplicar en cualquier contexto, algunas veces se hacen muy populares y llegan a ser aplicadas en los paises vecinos.

Comment: Bienvenido a [spanish.se]. Te recomiendo visitar las secciones de [tour] y [help] para entender un poco mejor la filosofía de este sitio. Procura responder realmente a la pregunta. Vota para respaldar una pregunta existente o deja un comentario para un apunte breve. Crea una respuesta nueva si va a ser _significativamente_ distinta a las ya existentes en algún sentido (de lo contrario es redundante). Tal como está ahora, esta publicación parece más un comentario a otra respuesta. Dale a [edit] y añade algo de contenido propio.